# How to receive a notification for each new message in a conversation?

Tags: notifications, inbox-by-gmail

If I have a conversation with unread messages, I get no new notifications for new messages in the conversation. Is there a way to get these notifications?

Answer (score 0):

On Android, go to settings, then bundle notifications. There should be a little bell icon next to each category that you want notifications about. This took me forever to realize how to fix, but much better now! Good luck.

Comment: By "On Android", did you mean "(In Inbox app) on Android"?